# Airflow: is there a way to see how macros expanded in your bash command?

Tags: airflow

In the airflow UI, under the Task Instance details, I see Attribute: bash command

```
python COMMAND.py --sdate {{ ds_nodash }} --edate {{ ds_nodash }}
```

is there a way to show how the macros resolved? I'm using airflow v2.5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the Render tab.

```
BashOperator(
    task_id='bash',
    bash_command="python COMMAND.py --sdate {{ ds_nodash }} --edate {{ ds_nodash }}",
)
```

[image]